# How to apply the Principal of Atom Conservation (POAC)

Tags: physical-chemistry, mole

27.6 g $\ce{K2CO3}$ was treated by a series of reagents so as to convert all of its carbon to $\ce{K2Zn3(Fe(CN)6)2}$. Calculate the weight of the product.

I am asking here is that, why we are  applying POAC only on Carbon atom not on Potassium Atom.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. What is "POAC"? Potassium acetate? What do you mean by "convert all of its carbon to K2Zn3[Fe(CN)6]2"? A nuclear fusion? Why did you mention *single* C and K atoms?

Comment: POAC means Principal of atom Conservation

Comment: *re: Why only to carbon atom?* --  Because that is how the problem is worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the question it is specifically written
"All of carbon of K2CO3 has been converted ".
Whereas it has not mentioned anything about potassium.
You have to understand that K2CO3 is conberted to K2Zn3(Fe(CN)6)2 by a series of reactions therefore there might be other potassium compounds which had been formed by the series of reactions.
But as it is given all of carbon converted therefore out of the series of reactions there was only one carbon containing compound K2Zn3(Fe(CN)6)2 .
Hope this helps..